# Maximum value returned by getnstimeofday

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

I am implementing a kernel module in which I need to measure the time between some events. To do so I use the function *getnstimeofday* to get the current timestamp in nanoseconds. I am then calculating the time between two events like:

```
nsecs_elapsed = t2 - t1;
```

However, the calculation is incorrect when the nanoseconds counter wraps around (overflow and begins again counting from zero), in which case I get a t2 minor than t1. If this is the case I want to calculate the amount of nanoseconds elapsed in the following way:

```
nsecs_elapsed = (POSSIBLE MAX_VALUE_TV_NSEC - t1) + (++t2);
```

Where "POSSIBLE_MAX_VALUE_TV_NSEC" should be the maximum possible value returned by the function *getnstimeofday*.

Now, this function (i.e. *getnstimeofday*) fills this information in the *tv.nsec* member of a *struct timespec* variable (whose address must be passed as parameter to the function *getnstimeofday*).
Since *tv.nsec* is of type *long* I though the maximum value of a *long* variable could be the maximum possible value returned by this function, but according to the my observations this is not the case.

From this function (i.e *getnstimeofday*) I always get the number of nanoseconds as a 9 digit number, so I am under the supposition that the maximum value that this function returns should be maybe *999999999*, but I would like to have some confirmation about this. I haven't found such information anywhere and when looking at the kernel'S code, it is still not clear to me if there is a maximum possible value returned by this function other than the maximum value of an *signed long*.

Does anybody knows if the returned value of *getnstimeofday* is delimited by some maximum value?
Or do you have any idea of where I can look at for this info.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getnstimeofday` fills **two fields** in the structure:

- *tv_sec* with total number of seconds,
- *tv_nsec* with the rest nanoseconds

These two fields cannot overflow in total: it takes several hundreds of years to overflow `tv_sec` part.

Since there is 10^9 nanoseconds in a second, the maximum value of `tv_nsec` field is 999999999, as you have guessed.

Comment: Wow... ok. It is really simple and it makes total sense.... never thought about that. Thanks for the answer!